# Execute mutation from modal in React native

Tags: react-native, apollo-client

I have a RootSearchStack like this in React native.

```
 const SearchStack = createStackNavigator({
    Profiles: Profiles,
    ProfileScreen: ProfileScreen,
 }) 


 const RootSearchStack = createStackNavigator({
      SearchScreen: SearchStack,
      ModalScreen: ModalScreen
    },{
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'none',
      })
```

From Modal screen user type in some string and push button to close Modal.
What I want to do is, after closing modal, I want to execute query based on string typed by user from SearchStack Profiles. I am using ApolloClient not Redux. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  can pass params to SearchStack.
Based on that param I can trigger query.

```
navigation.navigate('Main',
            { screen: "Home",
              params: {
                language: language,
              }
})
```